# emberjs - best practice to built an app?

Tags: javascript, performance, model-view-controller, memory, ember.js

I'm here cause I ask me some questions about emberjs framework and the best way to built an app with it... There are some questions that I hope someone can answer to me :

1. Is there any built-in system to manage memory efficiently ?
2. How to manage the controllers/views/models to be instanciated and destroyed during the app lifecycle ?
3. Have we to declare all our controllers and views at the starting of the app ?
4. Is there a way to auto-instantiate an view's controller when a the view is added to the DOM by the main controller (or the stateManager) ?

To resume my situation, I've testing ember's features and understanding all of that pretty well. But now, I'm a little bit confusing and don't know how to structure my app. When to instanciate views and its controllers, where and when to destroy view's controller for memory performance, etc...

Is there some of you that have been like me at this time and have some answers for me ?

All answers and help is really appreciated and I thank you already now for your feedback(s)

See you guys !

Edit : I'm using emberjs with requireJs to be able to separate my javascript files. Is there any best solution or built-on one to do that ?

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

requirejs isnt suitable for emberjs, Ember is build on top of a simpler require() from minispade.js, which isnt AMD.

Someone suggested me 2 cool grunt tasks to work with ember.js

- grunt-neuter         :  just use require('module'), so neuter can concat your app in the right order
- grunt-ember-template : compiles your template file into one global template.js, easy to work with.

i personally manages my app like HMVC, and i require each module files into its own moduleController, my app.js only inits each modules index controller, so i know what module is loaded when i look at my app.js

```
- app.js
- modules/
     -- module1
         - module1Controller.js // initiate this in the app.js, which ain't required for ember
         - module1Model.js      // (if non ember) returns static methods that can be used by other modules
         - module1View.whatever // this should be compiled into the template.js, just easier to manage in the same folder
     -- module2
     -- module3 ...
```